# What is SWD\WPDBUSENUM\{ID} in Event viewer DriverFrameworks-UserMode?

Tags: usb, event-viewer

I was tracing USB connection log with Event Viewer. So usually the log is about USB type device but I found this: `The UMDF Host Process ({8d3f38d1-e441-486f-8564-29dd1d6f2c3d}) has been asked to load drivers for device SWD\WPDBUSENUM\{91E9CC34-53E2-11ED-A56D-A497B1338893}#0000000000008000.`
and I don't understand what is this. Please explain me what is this.